# Are quantifiers a primitive notion?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Are quantifiers a primitive notion? I know that one can be defined in terms the other one, so question can be posed, for example, like this: is universal quantifier a primitive notion?  I know, that $\forall x P (x) $ can be viewed as a logical conjunction of a predicate $ P $ being applied to all possible variables in, for example, $\sf ZFC$. But how can one write such a statement down formally? Also, it seems you can not use the notion of a set to define the domain of discourse, because you are trying to build $\sf ZFC$ from scratch, and sets make sense only inside $\sf ZFC$. Obviously, I'm missing a lot here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not a primitive in Church's Type Theory.  It is based on lambda calculus.  For some lambda expression $P$, the quantifier is defined by making $\forall ~ P$ be defined as $P = \lambda n.\top$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(1) "$∀xP(x)$ can be viewed as a logical conjunction of a predicate $P$ being applied to all possible variables in, for example, ." Not so. The language of ZFC has only countably many terms $\tau$ so even if you allow infinite conjunctions of the form $P(\tau_0) \land P(\tau_1) \land P(\tau_2) \land \ldots$ you can't get something equivalent to the universal quantification over the uncountable domain of sets.

The basic point, of course, is this (a general observation about quantification, not especially about ZFC). In the general case, the language of a theory $T$ won't have a term $\tau$ for every object in the domain of quantification, so that a conjunction of wffs $P(\tau_0)$ -- even an infinitary one -- won't be equivalent to a universal claim $∀xP(x)$ in $T$.

(2) Is the universal quantifier a primitive notion? Well, grasping $∀xP(x)$ involves understanding something more than understanding conjunctions of wffs like $P(\tau)$ (whether finite or infinitary ones). It involves understanding that the quantification will be false if there is an unnamed object which doesn't satisfy $P$, compatibly with all the named objects satisfying $P$, and hence the conjunction of wffs of the form $P(\tau_0)$ being true. So we do indeed have a *new* notion here over an above the idea of a conjunction.

Comment: So is the universal quantifier a primitive notion?

Comment: I'm not sure there is an *absolute* notion of primitiveness: but it is an irreducible addition if so far we only have the idea of (finite or infinite) conjunctions of sentences.

Comment: What about the existential quantifier? Can it be formalised, in the light of the fact that it requires at least one object to satisfy some property to be true?

Comment: What goes for the universal and conjunctions here goes for the existential and disjunctions, as you would expect given the elementary $\forall/\exists$indefinability.

Comment: So, if we have a finite domain, can we view $\forall$xP(x) as a conjunction?  If we have a finite domain, can we view $\exists$xP(x) as a disjunction?

Comment: I think so. If the domain $D$ is *finite* (i.e. $D = \{ d_1, ... d_n \}$), we can expand the language *L* with a new *individual constant* $c_i$ for each elements $d_i \in D$. Then $\forall x \phi$ will be true iff $\phi(c_1) \land ... \land \phi(c_n)$.

Answer (score 6):

Note for example in PA  that even if $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ and $P(2)$ and ... are all theorems, it may happen that $\forall n\colon P(n)$ is not a theorem. Thus $\forall n\colon P(n)$ is in fact something different from $P(0)\land P(1)\land P(2)\land \ldots$ even if one were to accept such an infinte string as a wff (which  is a box of Pandora that should not be opened as in the next step such an infinite conjuntion would reuire an infinte proof and so on).
So this means that quantification *does* bear a "new" notion and should be considered primitive.

Comment: Why is it different?

Comment: @Trismegistos See [Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic#Metamathematics).

"... it is often possible to prove in Q every specific instance of a fact about the natural numbers, but not the associated general theorem. For example, 5 + 7 = 7 + 5 is provable in Q, but the general statement x + y = y + x is not."

Comment: @user1667423 Does it mean that proof for every instance of fact is little difference for each instance in Robinson arithmetic?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would say they are a primitive notion. Usually formal systems such as FOST only include one, since one of them can be defined in terms of another. For example, $\exists \alpha (\varphi(\alpha))$ is the same as $\neg (\forall \alpha (\neg \varphi(\alpha)))$, and $\forall \alpha (\varphi(\alpha))$ is the same as $\neg (\exists \alpha (\neg \varphi(\alpha)))$. But I agree with Hagen von Eitzen. A good example of this is that "TREE(n) is finite" can be proved for all n, but "for all n, TREE(n) is finite" cannot be proved.